# Hydrostatic pressure at the center of a water planet

Tags: gravity, fluid-statics

If we take an imaginary planet which consists entirely of water (i.e. a big ball of water in space), what would be the pressure at the center of it?

My friend argued that it would be zero, since the forces coming from every direction would cancel out, furthermore, at the center gravity is zero. I find this very hard to believe, but couldn't point out the fallacy in his argument (I'm a biologist).

What is the true answer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find the force of the compression at the core of a planet?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/110246/)

Comment: It's true that gravity vanishes at the core, but it's not true that pressure vanishes at the core. So you're correct in doubting his claim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P = \frac{GM^2}{8\pi R^4}$ in the approximation of constant density.

Where $P$ is the pressure at the center, $G$ is the gravitational constant, $M$ is the mass of the planet and $R$ is the radius of the planet.

see [Hydrostatic Equilibrium and Planetary Differentiation](http://www.asterism.org/tutorials/tut38%20Hydrostatic%20Equilibrium%20And%20Planetary%20Differentiation.pdf)

Pressure is maximal at the center of a planet.